# why does gitlab runner fail to start "org.freedesktop.systemd1"?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Hey I have a kubernetes cluster for a gitlab ci/cd pipeline.
There is a gitlab runner (kubernetes executor) running on it.

Sometimes the pipeline passes, but sometime I get

```
Waiting for pod gitlab-runner/runner-wyplq6-h-project-7180-concurrent-0lr66z to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotInitialized: "containers with incomplete status: [init-permissions]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: waiting for pod running: timed out waiting for pod to start. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

I checked the link but it says the kubernetes executor should not cause any problem with shell profiles.
So I ran `kubectl describe pod gitlab-runner/runner-wyplq6-h-project-7180-concurrent-0lr66z`

```
...
Events:
  Type     Reason                    Age   From               Message
  ----     ------                    ----  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled                 40s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned gitlab-runner/runner-wyplq6-h-project-7180-concurrent-0lr66z to bloxberg
  Warning  FailedCreatePodContainer  5s    kubelet            unable to ensure pod container exists: failed to create container for [kubepods besteffort pod6fe2669a-ae7f-47e3-8794-814767c14895] : Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Why does the runner fail to start `systemd` is there a way to fix that?

#### EDIT:

I looked at the pods running on the cluster and it seems that there is an issue with the runner. with `kubectl describe  pod gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-6b7bf4d766-9t4k6 -n gitlab-runner` I get:

```
  Type     Reason     Age                      From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                     ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m42s (x52196 over 21d)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed:
  Warning  BackOff    2m42s (x91155 over 21d)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

So there is an issue with the runner, but the error message says nothing about the cause

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#job-failed-system-failure-timed-out-waiting-for-pod-to-start

Answer (score 2):

According to the [troubleshooting docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#troubleshooting) for the kubernetes executor, you should increase your `poll_timeout` value in your `config.toml`:

> The following errors are commonly encountered when using the Kubernetes executor.
>
> `Job failed (system failure): timed out waiting for pod to start`
> If the cluster cannot schedule the build pod before the timeout defined by poll_timeout, the build pod returns an error. The Kubernetes Scheduler should be able to delete it.
>
> To fix this issue, increase the poll_timeout value in your config.toml file.

Answer (score 2):

**Job failed (system failure): timed out waiting for pod to start**

The following error occurs if the cluster cannot schedule the build pod before the timeout defined by poll_timeout, the build pod returns an error. The [Kubernetes Scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-lifetime) should be able to delete it.
To fix this issue, increase the `poll_timeout` value in your `config.toml` file.

**Error cleaning up pod and Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: waiting for pod running**

The following error occurs when Kubernetes fails to schedule the job pod in a timely manner. GitLab Runner waits for the pod to be ready, but it fails and then tries to clean up the pod, which can also fail.

To troubleshoot, check the Kubernetes primary node and all nodes that run a `kube-apiserver` instance. Ensure they have all of the resources needed to manage the target number of pods that you hope to scale up to on the cluster.

To change the time GitLab Runner waits for a pod to reach its **Ready** status, use the [poll_timeout](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#other-configtoml-settings) setting.

To better understand how pods are scheduled or why they might not get scheduled on time, read about the [Kubernetes Scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/).

Refer to the troubleshooting [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#job-failed-system-failure-timed-out-waiting-for-pod-to-start) for more details.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, I'm only able to work on this project for 1 Day a week. 
But I did increase the `poll_timeout` to 10 Minutes and it still doesn't work. Can it be that my kubernetes cluster is completely overworked?

Comment: I edited the question. I found that there is some issue with the runner, it restarted 90000 times in the last 3 weeks